# How can I get the relative path to a project from another project in the same solution?

Tags: c#, .net

I have two projects in my solution. I need to get relative path to the image file from first project in second project. How could I do this?

Already tried code from [this resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Resource_File_Pack_URIs___Referenced_Assembly) :

I reference ProjectB from ProjectA and use this (in ProjectA):

```
@"/ProjectB;component/images/prod-2809854.jpg"
```

Doesn't work.

I know I can use this (in ProjectA):

```
 AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

It will return base directory of ProjectA. Than I think I can parse the string, get the solution directory and append `ProjectB/images/` to it.

Is it the right way? Can it be done better?

Thanks!

**Edits:** as an example I run the code in console app (that is added to the same solution, cause on this stage I can't test my windows service app). I need to get image relative path:

```
// e.g. to check the GetMonitoringPath() method in main() in console app
Console.WriteLine(File.Exists(GetMonitoringPath())); 

public static string GetMonitoringPath()
    {
        return @"/WebStore;component/images/prod-2809854.jpg";
    }
```

File.Exists() returns false, but the file exists, I'm sure :)

Comment: Are both projects web projects?  If so, why can't you just use "../ProjectB/images/" in the HTML?

Comment: no, one project is web and another is windows service

Comment: Which project contains the image?  Is the image marked as an embedded resource in that project?  Is the image being dynamically generated?  None of the methods in the "System.IO" namespace (like File.Exists) work with the resource paths that the linked article talks about.

Comment: web project contains the image, image is copied into images/ folder. If these methods don't work, how to check, whether this path works or not in console app? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
<img alt="" style="cursor:pointer" src="../../../Booking/images/plus.gif" />
```

After typing src, VS will ask you to pick yr URL.

If this does not work, please post code regarding what exactly you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access a file in a web project from a console app or service, I would keep it simple and store the path to the web project in the other project's app.config appSettings.

If the files existed during compile time, embedded resources could be used to share the files between projects.  Other than that, some sort of path (relative or otherwise) needs to be used to reference the other folder.

Comment: How do I store relative path in App.config?

Comment: If your console app is running from "ProjectA\bin\debug", then the relative path would be something like:<add key="Web Images Folder" value="..\..\..\ProjectB\Images" />

Comment: For some reason this path is not working. I get: the path has illegal form